# Have an input with validation for email, trying to clear out error message and grey out input on click of checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I created a component using React hooks with an input field that runs a validation function for email whenever a user leaves the field empty or enters an incorrect format. I also have a checkbox next to the input with a function to disable the input field whenever a user clicks it. The problem I'm having now is that even when the field is disabled by the checkbox, the error message related to format still displays underneath. I'm trying to clear the error messages and grey out the input field whenever a user clicks the checkbox. I have a codesandbox running here: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-breeze-2ly5h and my full component below

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {
  Col, Row, Icon, Input, Tooltip
} from 'antd'
import Checkbox from '../elements/Checkbox'
import Markup from '../core/Markup'

function validateEmail(value) {
  const errors = {}
  if (value === '') {
    errors.email = 'Email address is required'
  } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(value)) {
    errors.email = 'Email address is invalid'
  }
  return errors
}

const CustomerDetails = ({ customer }) => {
  const { contact = {}, account = {}, site = {} } = customer || {}
  const [disableInput, setDisableInput] = React.useState(false)
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState({})
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState(contact.email)

  function onBlur(e) {
    setErrors(validateEmail(e.target.value))
  }

  function clearInput() {
    setInputValue(' ')
  }

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    setInputValue(event.target.value)
  }

  function CheckboxClick() {
    if (!disableInput) {
      clearInput()
    }
    setDisableInput(prevValue => !prevValue)
  }


  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col span={10}>
          <h4>
            PRIMARY CONTACT EMAIL &nbsp;
          </h4>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col span={8}>
          <StyledInput
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            disabled={disableInput}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            isError={!!errors.email}
          />
          {errors.email && <ErrorDiv>{errors.email}</ErrorDiv>}
        </Col>
        <Col span={2} />
        <Col span={8}>
          <StyledCheckbox
            value={disableInput}
            onChange={CheckboxClick}
          /> EMAIL
          OPT OUT{' '}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
}



const Container = styled.div`
  text-align: left;
`
const StyledCheckbox = styled(Checkbox)`
  &&& {
    background: white;

    input + span {
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      border: 2px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.black};
    }

    input + span:after {
      width: 12.5px;
      height: 20px;
    }

    input:focus + span {
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
    }
  }
`

const StyledInput = styled(Input)`
  max-width: 100%;
  background: white;

  &&& {
    border: 2px solid ${props => (props.isError ? '#d11314' : 'black')};
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 35px;
  }
`

const ErrorDiv = styled.div`
  color: #d11314;
`


export default CustomerDetails
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-sun-svb37

```
function CheckboxClick() {
if (!disableInput) {
  clearInput();
}
setDisableInput(prevValue => !prevValue);
setErrors({});
```

}

> update the error state with default value to reset the error

Comment: I need to run the validation again or at least set the error again if someone clicks the checkbox a second time making the input field active again. Any ideas on how to do this?